# como executar uma query insert em um intervalo de tempo com mysql

Tags: php, mysql, servidor

Eu preciso executar uma query insert todo dia às 23:59 com MySQL, sem precisar acessar o sistema

```
INSERT INTO TB_ESTOQUE_DIARIA (ID_PRODUTO, ESTOQUE, DATA) 
SELECT ID, ESTOQUE_ATUAL, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() FROM TB_PRODUTO
```

Não sei se essa informação ajuda mas meu servidor é o hostinger.

Comment: tem que verificar isso com a hostinger, procure mais sobre `CRON`

Comment: Ah obrigado, é isso mesmo. Eu só to com uma dúvida, não sei se todos os servidores são assim mas o hostinger cria um arquivo wp-cron.php, nesse arquivo eu faço rodar minha query em php normalmente certo?

Comment: qualquer arquivo .php roda no servidor php tem que anexar no serviço do sistema linux ... !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode acessar seu phpmyadmin do MySQL, acessa o banco de dados e vai em eventos (Event scheduler), fica ao lado de rotina. Lá você define a periodicidade da execução dessa query, vai ser a solução mais rápida neste momento.

Uma outra opção seria ter acesso ao crontab, neste caso é possível executar qualquer comando que você utiliza no SSH, recomendo estudar esta segunda, pois é muito util.